# UnityPlayer blackScreen on a subActivity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

On a android Studio project, when i switch to a another Activity who contains also a UnityPlayer, the UnityPlayer display a BlackScreen on the subActivity.

I am on Arcore project where i use Android studio for have a good interface and easy to implement, i use the last Unity version and Android studio, and every last android librairy(Androidx).
I needed to open the Unity view on a another activity, but do not seems to working. And every research done on google send me to answer who do not resolve my problem or else to add a android:process on my manifest.xml, but impossible to get it to work.

Every code related to mUnityPlayer
Manifest.xml of the two activity:

```
[...]
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale|layoutDirection|density"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity"
                android:value="true" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ViewerPlaneActivity"
android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale|layoutDirection|density"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity"
                android:value="true" />
        </activity>
[...]
```

MainActivity of my application:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
[...]
    public UnityPlayer mUnityPlayer;
   public static UnityPlayerActivity currentActivity;
    private boolean switchToAnAnotherUnityAct=false;

[...]
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        mUnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewer_view_simple_viewer);
        replaceUnityPlayerOnFrameLayout();
        mUnityPlayer.getView().requestFocus();
        currentActivity = this;
[...]
}
    private void replaceUnityPlayerOnFrameLayout(){
        FrameLayout frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.unity_player_layout);
        if( mUnityPlayer.getView().getParent()==null)
        frameLayout.addView(mUnityPlayer.getView());
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if(!switchToAnAnotherUnityAct)mUnityPlayer.destroy();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(!switchToAnAnotherUnityAct)mUnityPlayer.pause();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(!switchToAnAnotherUnityAct){
            mUnityPlayer.resume();
            replaceUnityPlayerOnFrameLayout();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mUnityPlayer.start();
        switchToAnAnotherUnityAct=false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if(!switchToAnAnotherUnityAct)mUnityPlayer.stop();
    }
    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mUnityPlayer.lowMemory();
    }
    @Override
    public void onTrimMemory(int level) {
        super.onTrimMemory(level);
        if (level == TRIM_MEMORY_RUNNING_CRITICAL) {
            mUnityPlayer.lowMemory();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mUnityPlayer.configurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        mUnityPlayer.windowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    }
    public void onClickSizeSettings(View view) {
        FrameLayout frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.unity_player_layout);
        frameLayout.removeAllViews();
        switchToAnAnotherUnityAct=true;
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ViewerPlaneActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }
[...]
```

The sub-activity:

```
public class ViewerPlaneActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public UnityPlayer mUnityPlayer;
    public static ViewerPlaneActivity currentActivity;
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        currentActivity = this;
        mUnityPlayer= MainActivity.currentActivity.mUnityPlayer;
        setContentView(R.layout.viewer_plane_unit);
        FrameLayout frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.unity_player_layout);
        frameLayout.addView(mUnityPlayer.getView());
        mUnityPlayer.getView().requestFocus();
[...]
}
    private void replaceUnityPlayerOnFrameLayout(){
        FrameLayout frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.unity_player_layout);
        if( mUnityPlayer.getView().getParent()==null)
            frameLayout.addView(mUnityPlayer.getView());
    }
    @Override
    public void onTrimMemory(int level) {
        super.onTrimMemory(level);
        if (level == TRIM_MEMORY_RUNNING_CRITICAL) {
            mUnityPlayer.lowMemory();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mUnityPlayer.configurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        mUnityPlayer.windowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
         return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event);
    }
    public void onClickAnchorPlane(View view){
[...]
        finish();
    }
    @Override
    public void finish() {
        super.finish();
        FrameLayout frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.unity_player_layout);
        frameLayout.removeAllViews();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mUnityPlayer.pause();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        replaceUnityPlayerOnFrameLayout();
        mUnityPlayer.resume();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mUnityPlayer.start();
    }
```

The result than i expect is to see the UnityPlayer displayed, but i got just a blackscreen. And zero errors.

I precise than i do not get problem for return on my MainActivity where the UnityPlayer work and display correctly the viewer. Just the SecondViewer, where i got a blackscreen where i expect just to see the unity to display my plane and the camera.

Thank for your help.

Comment: i have not found where you init this
public static UnityPlayerActivity currentActivity; while you call mUnityPlayer= MainActivity.currentActivity.mUnityPlayer; in your sun activity

Comment: Sorry, i have failed my copy paste of my code here, this is just currentActivity=this.

Comment: why in your manifest your activity is  android:name=".UnityPlayerActivity" ? it should be ...MainActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For finish, i have found no solution to my problem so i have used two ViewStub on my main layout.